# Is bee pollen kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, honey

Other then having dubious reputation as nutritional supplement, is [bee pollen](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_pollen) kosher?
I remember reading somewhere it may contain bee parts, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Even honey contains bee parts.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not talking about microscopic parts.

Comment: I'm not either.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please elaborate. I have a honey jar at home, no insects part spotted.

Comment: I'm guessing you have super filtered processed honey? Ever had raw plain honey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

From the [Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/624/do-bee-dont-bee/):

> Bees have brushes on their legs which collect the pollen from the flowers.  The pollen is brushed toward the back of the bee and is pressed into baskets found on their legs.  The bees add traces of saliva and nectar to make a more effective “press,” because pollen is naturally dusty and requires a binding agent.  This popular health food product is kosher.

Footnote 10 in the linked article gives sources that the bee's saliva does not make the pollen non-kosher.